# mvn archetype:generate error when making a web application

Tags: maven

I was in the middle of installing Maven but encountered an issue in the terminal when saying mvn archetype:generate as I came across an error saying,

```
[INFO] Using following parameters for creating project from Archetype: webapp-j2ee14:1.3 
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.koushik.javabrains 
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: mywebapp 
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT 
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.koushik.javabrains 
[INFO] Parameter: packageInPathFormat, Value: org/koushik/javabrains  
[INFO] Parameter: package, Value: org.koushik.javabrains 
[INFO] Parameter: version, Value: 1.0-SNAPSHOT 
[INFO] Parameter: groupId, Value: org.koushik.javabrains 
[INFO] Parameter: artifactId, Value: mywebapp 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 7:47.706s 
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 02 09:49:10 CDT 2015 
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/309M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) on project MavenTestApp: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.InvalidPackaging: Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom' -> [Help 1] 
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException"
```

I was following the tutorials on the youtube for channel javabrains(specifically for Maven and here is the link, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpNnbBmh5J4&list=PL92E89440B7BFD0F6&index=6"

Comment: I didn't find any solution but am still trying hard. If you look on javabrains tutorial to the link i gave then you might get a better idea of what I have encountered. After I said mvn archetype:generate, I followed the instruction to specify but at the end i got the error message shown above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be doing this in a folder with an existing pom, the archetype is trying to add the new project as a module of current folders pom, but modules can only be added in pom.xml with a package of type "pom"